# How Can I bind a Nested JSON to Jqgrid in the Same Row

Tags: jqgrid

```
{
    "InventoryId": "51",
    "AssetID": "23",
    "FieldData": [
        {
            "Field": "Field 1"
        },
        {
            "Field": "Field 2"
        },
        {
            "Field": "Field 3"
        },
        {
            "Field": "Field 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is a part of my JSON data. How can I bind this data to JQgrid? i need 
grid in following structure

```
AssetID | InventoryId | Field1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4
============================================================
        |             |        |         |         |
        |             |        |         |         |
```

Comment: Is the number of fields (`FieldData.length`) fixed (4) or variable? Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: No the length of the field isnt fixed,which is why i made it a list. im using jqgrid version 4.3.3 . Its a free version that i use

Comment: Is there exist a reason *why* you use the retro version 4.3.3? It was published 4.5 years ago (31 May 2012). It was the time of web browsers: IE9, Firefox 10, Chrome 19. Do you believe, that the retro version works good enough in Chrome 54, Firexox 50, Microsoft Edge or IE11? About your main question: you should formulate the requirements more clear. You know that jqGrid has `colModel`, which need be filled to create the grid. Thus one have to analyse the input data first to generate `colModel` for the grid. You included only *one item* of data. You should describe the input data more detailed

Comment: @Oleg lets assume that the length of fields are fixed, yes i know about colmodel but my question is how do i bind such nested JSON to jqgrid? If using a latest verison of Jqgrid solves the issue can I still know how it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One have to generate `colModel` elements with `jsonmap` in the form `jsonmap: "FieldData.0.Field"`, `jsonmap: "FieldData.1.Field"`, `jsonmap: "FieldData.2.Field"` and so on:

```
var mydata = [
        ...
    ],
    myColModel = [
        { name: "AssetID", label: "Asset ID", key: true,
            width: 70, template: "integer", frozen: true },
        { name: "InventoryId", label: "Inventory Id",
            width: 90, template: "integer", frozen: true }
    ];

for (i = 0; i < mydata[0].FieldData.length; i++) {
    myColModel.push({
        name: "field" + (i + 1),
        label: "Field " + (i + 1),
        jsonmap: "FieldData." + i + ".Field"
    });
}

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    colModel: myColModel,
    ...
});
```

The corresponding demo is https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ga9m44wm/

One can use callback function as the value of `jsonmap`. For example one can use

```
jsonmap: function (item) {
    return item.FieldData[0].Field;
}
```

for the first column,

```
jsonmap: function (item) {
    return item.FieldData[1].Field;
}
```

for the second column and so on. To generate the corresponding functions dynamically for `jsonmap` property of `colModel` one can use closures:

```
for (i = 0; i < mydata[0].FieldData.length; i++) {
    myColModel.push({
        name: "field" + (i + 1),
        label: "Field " + (i + 1),
        jsonmap: (function (index) {
            return function (item) {
                return item.FieldData[index].Field;
            }
        })(i)
    });
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ga9m44wm/1/

There are some additional important things, which one have to follow in case of loading the data from the server and the usage of `loadonce: true` option. The additional options, which one should use depends on the version of jqGrid, which you use and from the fork of jqGrid which you use. I used in my demos [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.5, the fork of jqGrid, which I develop starting with the end of 2014. Because you still use retro version 4.3.3, I tried to povide you the code, which uses only the oldest functionality of jqGrid.